# SharePoint Security Groups

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am looking to set up a new security group called Head Company which will include existing security groups on my SharePoint like Child Company 1, Child Company 2 etc. This is to allow say the Company Group CEO manager access to all the Companies the Head Company owns.

Unfortunately SharePoint does not seem to allow it ?
Error: SharePoint Groups cannot contain other SharePoint Groups. Remove the SharePoint Group from the Users box and try again.

Is this something you guys have done on SharePoint, or something perhaps you have been able to work round?

This problem messes up my master plan in terms of how I was going to set this up ! Double drat !

SHAREPOINT 2010

Answer (score 0):

If you could switch to using AD groups then you can put AD groups within each other however this also has drawbacks trying to manage it all.

A restructure may be time consuming but would make it easier to manage in the future. And i am sure you can move sites within subsite fairly easily now Check this out

http://movesites.codeplex.com/